# Return True if Array Contains a Specific String - JSONata

Tags: jsonata

Is there a way in JSONata to have a function return TRUE if it finds a specific string within a provided array? For example I have an array of colors:

const myArray =  [red,blue,green,pink]

I am trying to figure out an expression that would search that array for "blue" and return true if it finds the value.

On the JSONata documentation, I found a function called $boolean(arg)that I think I would need to use but I'm not sure how to implement it. The [documentation](https://docs.jsonata.org/boolean-functions) shows an argument type option as "array: contains a member that casts to true", but I can't really tell how to implement it.

Would it be as simple as $boolean(myArray, "blue")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `in` operator is what you need. See https://docs.jsonata.org/comparison-operators#in-inclusion

In your case, the expression `"blue" in myArray` will return `true`.  See https://try.jsonata.org/r0q7GnSOh

Comment: This was it! Thanks for the help Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

edit: Thought this was python, but maybe you could use something similar for JSONata

you can make a for loop with an if condition to check your condition

```
listOfStrings = ['red','green','blue']

for strings in listOfStrings:
    if listOfStrings[strings] == 'blue':
        return True
```